# How to configure Kafka SSL brokers listeners

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to configure Kafka SSL listeners with trust and key stores, but I'm facing below issue

**org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to domain-node1.com:9093Cannot assign requested address: bind**

My configuration in server.properties

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://domain-node1.com:9093

ssl.keystore.location=localpath/test.pfx
ssl.keystore.password=****
ssl.key.password=*****
ssl.truststore.location=localpath/test.jks
ssl.truststore.password=***
```

My configuration in client-ssl.properties

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=localpath\teststore.p12
ssl.truststore.password=******
```

Commands which I'm trying to run (haven't made any changes to zookeeper properties)

```
kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties
kafka-console-consumer.bat --topic testTopic --group testGroup --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning ../config/client-ssl.properties
```

so I need to connect successfully to external domain (domain-node1.com:1000) and start consume messages from command prompt using above commands I'm not sure what exact configuration changes required ?

Do I need to do any other listeners configuration to listeners, advertised listeners, controller ? not sure. please assist me here ?

Comment: You need to be a super user (root) to bind to ports < 1024.

Comment: This is a external domain (SSL://domain-node1.com:1000) all other parties are using. I'm not sure what you really meant super user can you point to any reference document please ?

Comment: That is irrelevant; for Unix-like systems, ports 1-1023 are reserved for the operating system. https://www.thegeekdiary.com/which-network-ports-are-reserved-by-the-linux-operating-system/ You can't bind them (listen on them) unless the process is running as `root` `>...there are 3 different kinds of network service ports:

- The Well Known Ports (0-1023) – which are reserved for the operating system and core services.
- The Registered Ports (1024-49151) – which can be used by applications, specific services, and users.
- The Dynamic and/or Private Ports (49152-65535)`

Comment: Along with the above, you shouldn't run Kafka server as root user account to workaround those restrictions... Why TLS must be on port 1000? Most people just do 9093, for example

Comment: Guys I'm sorry my port running on 9093. I have edited my question now. I'm facing issue on 9093.